# Making an image move in 4 directions in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

Struggling to make my 'cowboy' image move across the screen in all 4 directions. Nothing happens whenever I press the keys. Help please. This is based off the exercise questions in Python Crash Course.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Move the Cowboy")


cowboy = pygame.image.load('images/cowboy.bmp')
cowboy = pygame.transform.scale(cowboy, (50, 50))


run = True

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill((240,237,207))

    cowboy_rect = cowboy.get_rect()

    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    screen_center = screen_rect.center

    cowboy_rect.center = screen_rect.center
    cowboy_rect.x = cowboy_rect.width
    cowboy_rect.y = cowboy_rect.height

    cowboy_x = float(cowboy_rect.x)
    cowboy_y = float(cowboy_rect.y)


    screen.blit(cowboy, screen_center) 


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        cowboy_x -= 5
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        cowboy_x += 5
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        cowboy_y -= 5
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        cowboy_y += 5

    pygame.display.update()
```

pygame.quit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting this in: `screen.blit(cowboy, screen_center)`, you are saying that this image will appear at the center of the screen. You want it to appear at `(cowboy_x, cowboy_y)`, as these are the positionment variables you defined. Here is a working version of your code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Move the Cowboy")


cowboy = pygame.image.load('images/cowboy.bmp')
cowboy = pygame.transform.scale(cowboy, (50, 50))

cowboy_x, cowboy_y = 0, 0

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill((240,237,207))

    screen.blit(cowboy, (cowboy_x, cowboy_y)) 


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        cowboy_x -= 1
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        cowboy_x += 1
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        cowboy_y -= 1
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        cowboy_y += 1

    pygame.display.update()    
pygame.quit()
```

> I took the liberty of taking out some completely useless lines of code, and of bringing the stuff you didn't need to re-iterate out of the loop, to save processing space.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now and the code looks a lot clearer!

Answer (score 3):

You are putting the image at the middle of the screen with `screen.blit(cowboy, screen_center)`. Change `screen_center` to `cowboy_rect` as this stores the position of the image.

Also take the `cowboy_rect = cowboy.get_rect()` out of the loop as this resets it back to 0.

You are then putting the position of `cowboy_rect` to the center of the screen by doing `cowboy_rect.center = screen_rect.center`, take that out of the loop so it only happens once, not every frame. Then its getting changed to 50,50 by `cowboy_rect.x = cowboy_rect.width` and `cowboy_rect.y = cowboy_rect.height`, so take that out.

Then at the keys, change `cowboy_x -= 5` to `cowboy_rect.x -= 5` and do the same for the others.